# Conditions in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to add conditions to my canvas.
The #iconTel element is a checkbox. I want to make an icon appear on the canvas only if the checkbox is checked. Here's what I tried...but does not work. I've searched a lot on the web for this without success.

```
function updateClicked() {

    oCanvas.width = oCanvas.width;
    oCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);

   $('#iconTel').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        oCtx.font = "15px VonnesReg";     // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top";           // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("iconTel").value, 260, 172, 225);
    }
})
```

So when that checkbox is checked, the element needs to appear, and if it is unchecked, it disappears without erasing the whole canvas.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The common design pattern for canvas is that when changes are required to the canvas content, the canvas is cleared completely and all the newly desired content is redrawn. It sounds like you're fighting this common design pattern--especially given your comment about onKey messing with your content. An alternate to completely clearing the canvas would be to layer a second canvas directly on top of your current canvas (using CSS absolute positioning). Then you could draw/clear your optional content on that top canvas. ;-)

Comment: Thanks markE for your comment. I haven't thought of it, but that would be a good solution! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a `clearRect()` in the same area over your text, in this case I'm going to have the width of that rectangle be the same as the max-width of the text (you can change it if you wish).

```
if (this.checked) {
    oCtx.font = "15px VonnesReg";     
    oCtx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    oCtx.textBaseline = "top";           
    oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("iconTel").value, 260, 172, 225);
} else {
    // Clear Text
    oCtx.fillStyle = "#00ffff";    
    oCtx.clearRect(260, 172, 225, 15);
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqdv4cj/1/)

If you have items in the way of the rectangle over the canvas then what you will want to do is redraw your content after you changed the text. If you have a static background on your canvas (one that doesn't change over time), then you just need to save that context at the start and other than clearing the canvas, replace it with the starting context. For example:

```
// Initial Drawing Code 
initImgData=oCtx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

if (this.checked) {
    ...
} else {
    oCtx.putImageData(initImgData,0,0);
}
```

[**Here is a fiddle for that**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqdv4cj/2/)

Comment: This works great! The only thing is that I use the "onkeyup" event to make appear texts I'm tryping in multiple text boxes on the canvas. The function that is linked with the "onkeyup" event redraws the whole canvas every time a letter is typed in these text boxes...so it erases the newly added element via the checkbox. Is there a way to make the document verify that if the checkbox is checked when it redraws the canvas "onkeyup", the newly added element will remain there, or not depending if it is checked (sorry for my english, I'm doing my best to explain it correctly)